# How to automatically change the GIS data file on model runs?

Tags: gis, netlogo

**General context:** I have a model in NetLogo working with bees and resources in the landscape. I need to run the model with GIS data from one season of the year, and then I need to run the same model but with GIS data from another season of the year.
Objectively, I need to run the same model with two different initial conditions: GIS data 1 and GIS data 2.

**Question:** I would like to implement something that, at the end of every iteration with GIS data 1, automatically initializes the environment with the information from GIS data 2, running the model with this new data. Would you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by initialising and running the model. If they are simply sequential years then the second GIS isn't really an 'initial' condition and you can simply have the GIS data change at an appropriate tick (such as tick 53 if each tick represents a week). If you want to run the model with different initial GIS conditions, then these are separate model runs, not sequential.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a global variable which is used to check what run is being run.

In some degree of pseudocode:

```
globals [
  control-variable
]

to setup
  clear things  ; see note about this below in the answer.
  ifelse (control-variable = 0)
    [import GIS data 1]
    [import GIS data 2]
end

to go
  run-the-model
  set control-variable control-variable + 1
  manage-runs
end

to manage-runs
  ifelse (control-variable = 1)
    [setup
     go]
    [stop]
end
```

Note that, at the beginning of `setup`, I didn't use `clear-all` as the standard practice would suggest. This is because, as from the [NetLogo Dictionary](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#clear-all), `clear-all`:

> Combines the effects of clear-globals, clear-ticks, clear-turtles, clear-patches, clear-drawing, clear-all-plots, and clear-output.

... meaning that `control-variable` too would have been deleted at the beginning of the second `setup`.
Therefore, you should instead use all the `<clear-something>` that are relevant to your code AND manually clear all your globals apart from `control-variable`.